# Does Instant Enemy let me use abilities that only apply to a specific enemy on an enemy not of that type?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

What exactly does the spell mean when it says 'all purposes'.  For example:

If I have the ['hatred'](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/dwarf/) racial trait, giving me a +1 bonus to attack v.s. goblins and orcs, and I use [*Instant Enemy*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/instant-enemy/) to count an enemy as a humanoid(orc), do I get the extra +1 to attack rolls?

If I use *Instant Enemy* to count a kobold necromancer as undead, does my scroll of [*Undeath to Death*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/undeath-to-death/) affect him as well as his skeletal minions?

If I have cast *Instant Enemy* on a creature, can I designate it as my Quarry (via the 11th level ranger ability of the same name)?

How about if I have the feat [Orc Hewer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/orc-hewer-combat-dwarf/)?  If I designate a stirge as an orc, will I get a +2 circumstance bonus to hitting it after I fell its kin?

In general, what purposes are included in 'all purposes'?

Comment: Do you only want RAW answers, or are answers based on the consequences of interpretations also interesting to you?

Comment: @Thanuir I personally play games by their rules, but that's a playstyle and I'm happy to get an answer that uses some other sort of reasoning to answer this provided it's clear, useful, and well-supported. Game balance, for example, could be an interesting argument for what should and shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 4):

For reference, Instant enemy is an enchantment that targets one creature and has the following effect:

> With this spell you designate the target as your favored enemy for the remainder of its duration. Select one of your favored enemy types. For the duration of the spell, you **treat the target as if it were that type of favored enemy** for all purposes.

In a Paizo forums discussion on this very subject, we have the following quote from Paizo designer Owen Stephens:

> This is not an official response, BUT.
>
> **RAW says the target is treated as "that type of favored enemy," not that type of CREATURE**. So if an effect or ability triggers off a favored enemy, then yes it applies. But animal growth requires a creature to be a type of creature (animal), it does not care if the target is a specific kind of favored enemy.
> That's parsing, but I am am very comfortable with it even as a RAW solution.

Emphasis mine. Link: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rqvh?Is-Instant-Enemy-as-broken-as-it-sounds#3

As mentioned in the quote above, only the spell only affects abilities related to something being or not being a favoured enemy.

Comment: Could you include some information on what makes Owen Stephen's opinion on the matter relevant (he doesn't provide any support for his claims in his post so I am assuming this is an appeal to authority).  My research indicates he's worked for Paizo in the past and still works for Green Ronnin and Genius Games.  Does he have any sort of official capacity within the message boards?  He disclaimers himself at the beginning so I suspect he does and I just can't find it but you should make it more clear.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer The bolded part contains the argument. I am not particularly aware of the credentials of mr. Stephens; I know he has done some design work on D&D 3.

Comment: Designer commentary on the RAI is a totally valid approach that I normally upvote, I just 1) don't see Mr. Stephens as an authority on this and 2) don't see his argument as even vaguely tenable.  If the first, independent, clause is in fact intended as support for the second, dependent, one it seems like a non-sequitor.  I don't read your bolded statement as an attempt at supporting the claims, though, I read it as just saying how things are.  There's nothing wrong with making unsupported claims on an internet forum in an attempt to be helpful, I just don't find it a convincing answer

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I have difficulty seeing why the bolded part of the quote is not an argument. (It might not be a good one.)

Comment: A: "Please choose an integer" B:"I choose 4" Is now 4 a *number* or only an *integer*?

Comment: You may not like his answer, but as for today (and at the time when he posted that), he is still a developer at Paizo. He was out for about an year between 2013 and 2014, but came back to work on the modules line and the RPG Superstar. By overseeing the Superstar entries (which are made by non-developers), he has a word on what should become official or not in the game system. Maybe not THE word, but a word.

Comment: @ShadowKras That definitely helps support this answer and some mention of and link to his official role and proof of it respectively would but benefit this answer.

Comment: The link is already on the answer, you simply need to click on his profile name.

Comment: But if the paizo.com community has any weight: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2u8wf?Instant-Enemy-ranger-spell-clarification-needed

Answer (score 0):

### All of them

That's what 'all purposes' means.  Any time you use any of your abilities on a target or any creature is otherwise affected by you, count it as the type of favored enemy you picked when casting the spell.  When other creatures affect the target, though, they treat it as normal.

To go through the specific examples:

- race traits: yep, your 'favored enemy'-like race trait definitely works here. You treat the enemy as humanoid(orc) for all purposes, and you get the +1 to all humanoid(orc)'s.
- spells: yep, you count the kobold as 'Undead' so the spell that you cast affecting all Undead in a 40' burst affects it.
- class features: yep!  You count it as 'that type of favored enemy' for all purposes, so it's definitely counting as a favored enemy!  Also, while the Quarry ability can only be initiated on favored enemies, it won't go away just cause the spell ends-- valid targeting is only important when you initiate an ability
- feats: Yep, you count the stirge as humanoid(orc) for all purposes and the feat gives you a special +2 when used on humanoid(orc)'s.  You get the +2.

Comment: Spells do what they state to do and this spell makes the target creature count as a certain type of favoured enemy. It does not make the creature count as a certain creature type.

Comment: @Umbranus: this precision means you can't for example make a creature count as a "shadow", a "devil" or as a "citizen of Qadira": you can only choose types that are listed in the description of [favored enemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/#TOC-Favored-Enemy-Ex-). Explicitely if you choose for example "humanoid(orc)" then the target is considered as a "humanoid(orc)", and not only for the *favored enemy* class feature but "for all purposes".

Comment: The spell reads "... you treat the target as if it were that type of favored enemy for all purposes" it does not read "...you treat the target as if it were that creature type for all purposes". The stirge counts as favoured enemy humanoid (orc) for all purposes but it still does not count has being a humanoid (orc).

Comment: You are stretching the meaning of *all purposes* way too far beyond the scope of the spell.

Comment: By this logic, if you use Instant Enemy on yourself targeting Animals, your Intelligence drops to 1 or 2? I mean, it says "all purposes" and not "a few conveniently selected purposes" , right? http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types/#TOC-Animal

Comment: @ShadowKras The guy I know who generally rules that 'treated as' includes derived statistics responds: "unless otherwise noted in a creature’s entry".  Also there's a lot of precedence for animals with higher than 3 int.  But otherwise yes, you would treat yourself as if you had int "1 or 2", whatever that means.  (That wouldn't really work cause that's either a -4 or -5 int modifier so it's good that this particular example is not the case).

Comment: @ShadowKras I disagree because I rule you don't get any of that stuff-- you aren't an animal, you just count as one for all purposes.  That list isn't some sort of magical effect that says 'all animals get...', it's just a thing defining what 'animal' means.  Since you aren't an animal you don't get it.